# What is skin boost?

Tags: league-of-legends

Yesterday i played a ARAM game and I saw the <kbd>skin boost</kbd> button:

[image].

What is that?

I read the discription but I still don't get it.

If I click it, would I spend 95RP's to buy everyone in my team a random skin? Are those skins unlocked just for that game or would they be permanently associated with that summoner?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those skins are just for that one game. The purchaser also gets 200 IP and everyone else on his team gets 100 bonus IP whether you win or lose!

It's just a cool, cheap way for everyone on your team to play with a skin they don't own, for a champion they may not play often.

Comment: Sorry, but the bonus is not 200 pi?

I tried it yesterday and gave me an improvement of 200 pi.

Comment: No only 100. Its possible to stack the skin boosts though!

Comment: But the only one who bought it in the game was me, and earn 275 IP, 200 Bonus and 75 for the game.

Comment: Ill second NegroQueTose. I bought a skin boost - and was the only one to do so - and got an additional 200 IP from the source "skin boost" at the end of the match along the base IP reward for ARAMs

Comment: It is 200 IP for the purchaser, 100 for everyone else.  See: [5.8 patch notes](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-58-notes), where they were introduced.

Comment: @AaronDufour Thanks for clearing that up. I put your comment in the answer and gave you credit for it :)